# RSpec: Always execute before(:all) in begin/rescue

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, watir-webdriver

I'm writing Selenium tests, using Watir-Webdriver and RSpec, which can be a bit spotty when they're first being developed.  I've run into a situation where I want to create something on the UI in before :all, however it can throw exceptions (based on timing or poor loading).  When that happens I want to take a screenshot.

Here's what I have:

```rb
 RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.before(:all) do |group| #ExampleGroup
     @browser = Watir::Browser.new $BROWSER

     begin
       yield #Fails on yield, there is no block
     rescue StandardError => e
       Utilities.create_screenshot(@browser)
       raise(e)
     end
   end
 end
```

I run it and get an error:

> LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)

The reason I assumed yielding would work is RSpec's definition of before:

```
def before(*args, &block)
  hooks.register :append, :before, *args, &block
end
```

How can I wrap the code I've put in my `before :all` in a begin/rescue block without having to do it on every suite?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written in the before hook is the &block you're referring to in `RSpec::Hooks#before`. The hook yields to your code, then runs your tests after the yield is complete.

As for how to make this work, I think this should do:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ensures tests are run in order
  config.order = 'defined'

  # initiates Watir::Browser before all tests
  config.before(:all) do
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new $BROWSER
  end

  # executes Utilities.create_screenshot if an exception is raised by RSpec 
  # and the test is tagged with the :first metadata
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    example.run
    Utilities.create_screenshot(@browser) if example.exception && example.metadata[:first]
  end
end
```

This configuration requires the first test be tagged with metadata:

```
describe Thing, :first do
  it "does something" do
    # ...
  end
end
```

This way, you'll only take a screenshot at the beginning of your run for a failing test, and not after every failing test. If you'd rather not mess with metadata (or prefer your tests are run in random order), you could do something like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # initiates Watir::Browser before all tests
  config.before(:all) do
    @test_count = 0
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new $BROWSER
  end

  # executes Utilities.create_screenshot if an exception is raised by RSpec 
  # and the test is the first to run
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    @test_count += 1
    example.run
    Utilities.create_screenshot(@browser) if example.exception && @test_count == 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Edited. I had written `example[:first]` when I meant `example.metadata[:first]`.

Comment: I need to have the screenshot in before :all not before :each. I have navigation in the before :all intentionally. It needs to be there to remove some repetitiveness. I can use example.exception for the specific tests, but before :all gives example_group not example.

Comment: Ok, so you have setup code that you need run once before all tests. Do you need the screenshot to be taken after the first test if there's a failure or after all tests if there's a failure? Or is it something else that I'm missing entirely?

Comment: I already have the ability to take a snapshot during a test by using example.exception.  I need to take a snapshot in the before :all stage.  This is where I log in and navigate to a page I'm testing.  Currently the methods being called in it are wrapped in a big begin/rescue block that's a bit clunky.  I'm thinking it's all unnecessary code if I can essentially describe what's above.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  Instead of `begin/rescue` in the `before :all` hook,

```
config.after :each do
  example_exceptions = []
  RSpec.world.example_groups.each do |example_group|
    example_group.examples.each do |example|
      example_exceptions << !example.exception.nil?
      end
    end
  has_exceptions = example_exceptions.any? {|exception| exception}
  #Handle if anything has exceptions
end
```